# Xamarin.Forms Android 7.0 searchbar

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin.forms, searchbar

The searchbar in forms doesn't appear on Android 7.0 devices, I am compiling with Android 6.0 not the latest version. The issue is apparently a google problem with calculating a height of the searchbar that results in a height of zero, thus no searchbar. I want to implement a searchbar size in XAML and only affect Android. Apparently, if I don't set the HeightRequest, Forms will use a default value or zero, so now the problem propagates to the other platforms. I read somewhere that if I set the HeightRequest to -1, it is invalid and Xamarin will calculate/default a height that makes sense and I can simply override the height for Android. I currently have this code in my XAML and it appears to work. I don't want to make a custom renderer, especially since the problem is apparently fixed in Android 7.1.

Anyone have a better solution?

Thanks
Alan

```
<SearchBar Text="{Binding Search}" Placeholder="Search order list" SearchCommand="{Binding SearchCommand}" >
            <SearchBar.HeightRequest>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
                            iOS="-1.0"
                            Android="40.0"
                            WinPhone="-1">                   
                </OnPlatform>
            </SearchBar.HeightRequest>
</SearchBar>
```

Comment: Tested your code with real device with android version 7.0, it works fine by my side. Maybe you can try to use another device for testing.

Comment: I tried the above on UWP and iOS, it worked anyway on Android 6.0 and previous, so if it worked on your 7.0, I think I'm good to go. Thanks for giving it a try for me.